Conflict of Interest
Should a plaintiff or defendant ask a prospective lawyer to check for conflict of interest before disclosing information to that lawyer in case the same lawyer has been hired by the opposing defendant or plaintiff in the same case? Why or why not?

The first thing a lawyer will do is run a conflict-of-interest check against their own database of all matters presently or previously handled by the firm. They will ask for the potential client's name and the names of possible defendants.
The Law Society of Ontario provides an example checklist
that a lawyer should be following.
If a conflict of interest is discovered, the lawyer should provide a non-engagement letter, explaining that they have discovered that they have a conflict of interest and cannot represent the would-be client.
Note that, among others, it recommends that "no file is opened, or confidential information obtained, before a conflict check is conducted and the results have been cleared." The lawyer should not start gathering any information (beyond that necessary for a basic subject area and conflicts check) from a potential client until the conflict check has revealed no conflicts of interest.
Such a conflict check is also required by American Bar Association Rule 1.7. This or substantially similar rules have been adopted by all state bar associations. See Idaho's for example.
It would not be out of place for a client to confirm this kind of check has been completed, especially if they have an actual conflict concern that they want some comfort about.

+1 Basically the same answer in the United States. Also, though, I'd add that it doesn't hurt for the client to ask to make sure this was done, especially if there is some reason to believe a conflict is more likely than usual.

What do you mean by "it recommends that 'no file is opened, or confidential information obtained, before a conflict check is conducted and the results have been cleared.'"?

@HelloDarkWorld It means that the lawyer should neither agree to take on the client's case nor should the client give the lawyer any of the client's confidential information, until it has been determined that the lawyer does not have a conflict of interest.

@JBentley What if just for consultation purposes? If neither parties has hired the attorney, then does conflict of interest exist if just for consultation purposes? What if later one party hires the attorney, then can that attorney use the confidential information the opposing party has disclosed against that opposing party in a lawsuit?

@bdb484 What if just for consultation purposes? If neither parties has hired the attorney, then does conflict of interest exist if just for consultation purposes? What if later one party hires the attorney, then can that attorney use the confidential information the opposing party has disclosed against that opposing party in a lawsuit?

@HelloDarkWorld I can't comment on this answer's jurisdictions but for solicitors in England and Wales confidentiality rules apply to "prospective and former clients" (SRA Code of Conduct rule 6.3 and glossary definition of "client". As soon as you communicate information to a lawyer where there is a possibility you might become that lawyer's client, the lawyer cannot reveal the information to anyone else.

@HelloDarkWorld In your scenario, the lawyer would have competing obligations: under rule 6.3 they would need to protect the confidential information of the first client. Under rule 6.4 they would need to tell the second client any information which is material to the case. Obviously the lawyer cannot do both. The lawyer therefore has to inform the second client that he can no longer act for them unless both clients consent and confidentiality safeguards are put in place (rule 6.2).

@HelloDarkWorld That's a good but different question. You should post a new question.

ALWAYS! Even as an Expert Witness and Examiner in Digital Forensics, I'd ask and make sure too that there weren't any parties involved that could cause a conflict.  I testified in such a hearing in KY.

Personal anecdotes are not answers
